# Problem with Stored Procedures in PHPmyAdmin

Tags: sql, database, random, phpmyadmin, procedure

Attempting to perform operations with a random integer in SQL.

The following code works perfectly as intended when run as pure SQL, but triggers a syntax error when attempting to save it into a stored procedure.

```
SET @sample_count = (SELECT count(*)
    FROM cinder_sample);
    
SELECT @sample_count;
    
SET @random_ID = (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*@sample_count));

SELECT @random_ID;
```

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

The exact error triggered is:

"The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `play_random_sp`() NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER DELIMITER // SET @sample_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM cinder_sample)// SELECT @sample_count// SET @random_ID = (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*@sample_count))// SELECT @random_ID"

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '// SET @sample_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM cinder_sample)// SELECT' at line 1"

Comment: See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-delimiter/

Comment: Add the exact error to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Tried Adding the line to the top "DELIMITER //"  (as well as several other delimiters (and changing the semicolons accordingly),  but the same error is triggered

Comment: Added exact error to question

Comment: Where are your `BEGIN` and `END`?

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1!  It was the BEGIN/END!